# couldn't authenticate google drive api from an app run on aws server from a remote laptop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-drive-api, streamlit

I have build a pipeline between a streamlit app and google drive. Where people can use google drive to work there and sync back with the streamlit app and then sync again to gdrive, so and forth.

Problem is, when users try to authenticate the app with their google drive account, following issue pops up on my AWS EC2 server:

```
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=221699818561-ikl8emobsgi98ts9lr116uh36kok4grs.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

It works fine from my computer, but doesn't authenticate from other users. If anyone does have some knowledge on how to tackle this issue, would help me alot.

Comment: This might be an issue of the local host being used as a reference when trying to access the API due to the client id and the URI configuration, which URI have you added ?

Comment: I haven't add any URI. When I try to add ```http://3.110.107.174:8502``` which is generated when running the app in EC2 server, it says invalid URI. Plz let me know if I miss something here

Comment: Try adding this URI over the developer console on gcp:  `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Thankyou! After adding http://localhost:8080 this error is comes, ```The OAuth client was deleted.
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 401: deleted_client```

Comment: It seems you have deleted the credentials over the developer console, go back on the console and recreate the credentials and update the old token.